# Angular FormControl on <input> displays [object Object]

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Using Angular 7.

Have an `<input>` tag like the following:

```html
<input id="foo" type="text" class="bar" [formControlName]="'product'" 
 autocomplete="off [ngModel]="formGroup.controls.product.value" [readOnly]="true"/>
```

Eventually, `myControl.setValue('some string');` is called.

The result is the `<input>` element displays `[object Object]`.

I am trying to display the string from the `setValue()` call.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: can you share more code ?? 

Comment: FormControlName must be place inside fromGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this you don't need to use `[ngModel]` you set product control directly

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <input id="foo" type="text" class="bar" formControlName="product" 
       autocomplete="off"  [readOnly]="true"/>
    <button (click)="update()">Update</button>
</div>
```

*component*

```
 form:FormGroup;

  constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
      this.form = fb.group({
        product:'init data'
      });
  }

  update(){
    this.form.get('product').setValue('Updated...')
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-th5b7m)

incase you just have single form control you have to use [formControl] directive

```html
  <input id="foo" type="text" class="bar" [formControl]="myControl" 
       autocomplete="off"  [readOnly]="true"/>
    <button (click)="update()">Update</button>
```

*component*

```js
  myControl:FormControl

  constructor() {
      this.myControl = new FormControl('init data')
  }

  update(){
    this.myControl.setValue('Updated...')
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-893vun)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[ngModel]` section of the input, that isn't needed if you're using `formControlName` as well.

When setting the value, we can't see how you're specifying `myControl` but the equivalent code would be:

```
this.formGroup.controls['product'].setValue('my string');
```